Where is the error in evaluating this series?$\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$
Where is the error in evaluating this series?
$$\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}$$
My attempt:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}&=\frac{1}{2ix}\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n-ix}-\frac{1}{n+ix}\\&=\frac{1}{2ix}\left[{\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+ix} -\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n-ix}}\right]\\&=\frac{1}{2ix}(\psi(ix)+\gamma)-(\psi(-ix)+\gamma))\\&=\frac{1}{2ix}(\psi(ix)-\psi(-ix))=\frac{1}{2ix}(-\pi\cot(i\pi x)-\frac{1}{ix}) \end{align}$$
we have :
$$\cot(i\pi x) = i\frac{e^{-\pi x}+e^{\pi x}}{e^{-\pi x}-e^{\pi x}}$$
therfore:
$$\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{2ix}\left({-\pi  i\frac{e^{-\pi x}+e^{\pi x}}{e^{-\pi x}-e^{\pi x}}}\right)+\frac{1}{2x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2x}\left({  \frac{e^{-\pi x}+e^{\pi x}}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}}\right)+\frac{1}{2x^2}$$
but in the book SUMMATION OF SERIES COLLECTED BY L. B. W. JOLLEY, M.A. (cantab.), M.I.E.E. proplem 124 page 22
The answer has been provided
$$\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{2x}\left({  \frac{e^{-\pi x}+e^{\pi x}}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}}\right)-\frac{1}{2x^2}$$
I can't figure out where I did wrong??  Are there other ways to evaluate this series????

The series representation of the digamma function is $$\psi(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{\color{red}{n=0}}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{n+z}\right)$$
whereas your series starts at $n=1$. Therefore, you should have $$\begin{align}&\frac{1}{2ix}\left[{\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+ix} -\sum_{n=1}\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n-ix}}\right]\\=\,&\frac{1}{2ix}\left[\psi(ix)+\gamma-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{ix}\right)\right]-\left[\psi(-ix)+\gamma-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{-ix}\right)\right]\\=\,&\frac{1}{2ix}\left(\psi(ix)-\psi(-ix)+\dfrac{2}{ix}\right)\\=\,&\frac{1}{2ix}\left(\psi(ix)-\psi(-ix)\right)-\dfrac{1}{x^2}\end{align}$$
This last $-\dfrac{1}{x^2}$ term converts your $\dfrac{1}{2x^2}$ into the correct $-\dfrac{1}{2x^2}$, as in the book's answer.

In the series involving the digamma function $\psi(z)$, you forgot the term corresponding to $n=0$. Once corrected, your calculation becomes:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2+x^2}&=\frac{1}{2ix}\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+ix}\right) -\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n-ix}\right)\right]\\&=\frac{1}{2ix}\left[\left(\psi(ix)+\gamma\color{red}{-1+\frac1{ix}}\right)-\left(\psi(-ix)+\gamma\color{red}{-1+\frac1{-ix}}\right)\right]\\&=\frac{1}{2ix}\left(\psi(ix)-\psi(-ix)\color{red}{+\frac2{ix}}\right)
\\&=\dots\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2x}\left({  \frac{e^{-\pi x}+e^{\pi x}}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}}\right)+\frac{1}{2x^2}\color{red}{-\frac1{x^2}}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2x}\left({  \frac{e^{-\pi x}+e^{\pi x}}{e^{\pi x}-e^{-\pi x}}}\right)\color{red}-\frac{1}{2x^2}.\end{align}$$
